# Angular: HttpClient Post Request not hitting the Asp.net MVC Controller's Action Method

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, typescript, httpclient, connection-refused

I'm new to Angular Development!
Here I'm developing a sample angular project. From this Angular Sample, I have to make HTTP calls to the ASP.NET MVC Web Application. I have to connect to the MVC's Controller Action Methods.

Initially, I created an angular application using CLI.

Then I created a new component using **ng generate component ComponentName**

Here My component name will be **MaterialList**

**Material List Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from '../testservice.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-material-list',
    templateUrl: './material-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./material-list.component.css']
})
export class MaterialListComponent implements OnInit {
     sites: any = [{ Id: 0, Name: 'TMD | Texas  Machinery Depot' }];

     constructor(private testServ: TestService ) { }

     ngOnInit() {
       this.testServ.SignInToHMIDS().subscribe(login => {
           if (login) {
            console.log("Login Success");
           } else {
            console.log("Login Failed");
         }
      }, (err) => {
           console.log(err.message);
      }, () => {
         console.log('completed');
     });
      this.testServ.LoadMaterialListPage().subscribe(result => {
         var listData = JSON.stringify(result);
         console.log(listData);
      }, err => {
         console.log(err.message);
      }, () => {
        console.log('completed');
     });
  }

 }
```

**Material List Html file:**

```
<h1>Material Search</h1>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label style="font-weight:bold">Site</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="pCategory" name="pCategory">
            <option *ngFor="let s of sites" value={{s.Id}}>
                {{s.Name}}
            </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">

    </div>
  </div>
```

And Also, I have added a Service using **ng generate service serviceName**

Here my Service name is **TestService**

**TestService.ts:**

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
 import { SignInModel } from '../app/Models/RequestModels';

  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
export class TestService {
    public _hmidsLoginUrl: string = 'http://localhost:58861/Api/AuthorizationService/SignIn';
    public _materialListUrl: string = 
   'http://localhost:58861/Api/MaterialService/MaterialListOnPageLoad';

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

   }
   SignInToHMIDS() {
        var requestData = JSON.stringify({
           UserName: "test.u.login1.txt@mail.mil",
           Password: "TEST4587",
           NewSignIn: false,
           RememberMe: false
    });
    return this.http.post<SignInModel>(this._hmidsLoginUrl, requestData, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE'
          })
       }
     );
  }
 LoadMaterialListPage() {
      return this.http.get<any>(this._materialListUrl);
 }
}
```

And my Request Model Class is given below

```
export class SignInModel {
    UserName: string;
    Password: string;
    NewSignIn: boolean;
    RememberMe: boolean;
}
```

When I try to Connect the Angular POST Calls to the MVC Project, I have faced the **No Access-Control-allow-origin** Cors Issue. To Resolve this, I have followed the below steps

I have installed the **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors** package to the ASP.NET MVC Project.

Then I have added the below Code in the **WebApiConfig.cs** file. Inside the "Register" Method

```
config.EnableCors();
```

And then I added the "EnableCors" Attribute above the MVC Controller's name

**SignIn Controller and Action:**

```
 [EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
 public class AuthorizationServiceController : ServiceBase
```

**MaterialList Page controller and Action**

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
[Authorize]
public class MaterialServiceController : ServiceBase
```

After Configuring Above all, I have been facing these issues in the Angular Project Console

1. Http failure response for http://localhost:58861/Api/MaterialService/MaterialListOnPageLoad: 0 Unknown Error
2. GET http://localhost:58861/Api/MaterialService/MaterialListOnPageLoad net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
3. Http failure response for http://localhost:58861/Api/AuthorizationService/SignIn: 0 Unknown Error
4. POST http://localhost:58861/Api/AuthorizationService/SignIn net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

The Angular Project Output with Console Error is given below

[Angular Project Console Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDW2e.png)

---

---

**Note:**

1. In My MVC Project, once the user login into the application, he is allowed to access the other screens.
2. From this Case, Initially **Sign In and then Material List** API Calls are made from the angular project.

---

---

Any Help Related to the above Will be more helpful for me?